# Running a python script from PHP with Apache

Tags: php, python, apache

I have set up an Apache 2 server on a Raspberry Pi with an `index.php` which I can access from any computer on the network. In the same folder (`/var/www`) I also have a python script `test.py`.

The script works fine when running it manually. However, I want to be able to run the script in my browser by using php. I tried this:

```
<?php 

$command = escapeshellcmd('test.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;

?>
```

However nothing happens. I also tried using the full filepath `/var/www/test.py`, but that didn't work either.

Any suggestions on how I can get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things come to mind:

First, does the first line in the file contain the full path to the python interpreter? i.e:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Second, does the file have the appropriate file permissions. Can you you open it with the `www-data` user (same user as which your apache process should be running as)?

```
sudo -u www-data /var/www/test.py
```

Comment: I've now added the path to the python interpreter. I tried running the command, and this is the error I get: "Cannot create testVideo.raw": Permission denied. What my python script does is record a short video with my webcam and saves it as testVideo.raw. So yeah, I don't have permission to do that. Any suggestions?

Comment: `test.py` is trying to create the file `testVideo.raw` as the `www-data` user. You need to make sure that the directory where that file is being created allows the `www-data` user to write to it. Create a new private directory somewhere, change its owner using `sudo chown www-data:www-data /path/to/directory`, and write your raw file there.